# Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor can't apparently access classes in another assembly

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper, sitecore7.2

We are running Sitecore 7.2 and are exploring the use of Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor for a large project that's just getting underway. We're having problems.

We have a solution with the following: 
1. Base project for core reusable code
2. Base web project for reusable web code, controls, etc. (refers to # 1)
3. Project-specific project for domain model and other non-web code (refers to # 1)
4. Project-specific web project (refers to # 1, 2, 3)

Projects # 2 and # 4 are pointed to the same web root. We run multi-site instances of Sitecore, but this project is our first on version 7.x; the others will be migrated in due course.

In the GlassMapperScCustom GlassLoaders() method, we have this:

```
return new IConfigurationLoader[] { new SitecoreAttributeConfigurationLoader("{assembly name of project # 3}") };
```

For our first proof-of-concept, we located one domain-model class in project # 3, and tried to get Glass mapping working in project # 4. No dice. The following all return an item but without the fields filled in:

```
new SitecoreContext().GetCurrentItem<{class name}>()
new SitecoreContext().GetItem<{class name}>("path")
new SitecoreContext().GetItem<{class name}>(new Guid("Sitecore GUID"))
```

We've tried installing nuget package Glass.Mappers.Sc.CastleWindsor in all four projects, to no avail. We've also tried using a VersionDisabler, checking the site language, etc. but also didn't achieve success.

The Glass.Mapper.Sc tutorials and bits of sample code are inconsistent, which I suspect is part of the problem. Some of the tutorials show the older way of doing things, others the new, but we have now tried all ways shown in the tutorials for loading our classes.

This page...
http://www.glass.lu/download/glass-sitecore-mapper/
... seems to indicate that Glass only supports Sitecore through version 7.0. Is that accurate, or is it just more out-of-date information? The links seem to go to the old Sitecore Mapper website from that Marketplace page.

We need to get this working very soon, or we'll have to abandon the use of Glass for this large project, which we're loath to do because it will mean further use of the Custom Item Generator or naked item access. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: can you post the model you are trying to map encase there is a problem with the mapping markup?

Comment: More to the point, how are you setting up Castle Windsor?   Default installation only registers for the executing assembly, not any referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using an older version of Glass (2.0.11) in Sitecore 7.2 now, and I'm having no problems with that. Basically, this is how I load my assemblies from the `Global.asax` (no IoC involved):

```
using Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes;
var loader = new AttributeConfigurationLoader(new[] {
  "namespace, assembly",
  "namespace#2, assembly#2",
});

var ctx = new Glass.Sitecore.Mapper.Context(loader);
```

The class names might be a bit different, but this gives you a rough idea.

Also, I notice that we use the `namespace, assembly` notation when initializing Glass. Maybe that's the cause instead?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Glass are you using?  In recent versions, `SitecoreAttributeConfigurationLoader` is deprecated.  For basic use, you don't need to specify a configuration loader at all.  Try using the out-of-the-box GlassMapperScCustom.  If that doesn't work, try `Glass.Mapper.Configuration.Attributes.AttributeConfigurationLoader` instead.